# Html not being rendered when called from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display some html using a function call but it not rendering for some reason.

```
displayMenu() {
if (this.props.menu) {
 
  Object.keys(this.props.menu).map((key,index)=>{
    if(index==0){
      console.log("hi")
      return <li class="nav-item active">
      <a className="nav-link" id={key + "-tab"} data-toggle="tab" href={"#" + key} role="tab" aria-controls={key} aria-selected="true">{key}</a>
    </li>
    }else{
      return <li class="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" id={key + "-tab"} data-toggle="tab" href={"#" + key} role="tab" aria-controls={key} aria-selected="true">{key}</a>
    </li>
    }

  })
}

return <h1>hi</h1>
```

}

So I'm using bootstrap nav-tabs and I'm trying to create tabs base on items I have stored in a object called menu. So I'm writing this function so that the first tab is active and the rest are not. However, when I ran the code the tabs aren't rendering at all. However return at bottom

```
<h1>hi</h1>
```

does render. And my console.log("hi) also displays so I know I'm running through the code. Just not sure why its not rendering.

Comment: tried wrapping the html in backticks?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the value from `Object.keys(this.props.menu).map` to the render function, the returns are inside the callback and only return to `map`.

Assuming `displayMenu()` is called within the `render()` method, add `return` infront of `Object.keys` like so:

```js
function displayMenu() {

  if (this.props.menu) {
    return Object.keys(this.props.menu).map((key, index) => {
      if (index == 0) {
        console.log('hi');
        return (
          <li class='nav-item active'>
            <a
              className='nav-link'
              id={key + '-tab'}
              data-toggle='tab'
              href={'#' + key}
              role='tab'
              aria-controls={key}
              aria-selected='true'
            >
              {key}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <li class='nav-item'>
            <a
              className='nav-link'
              id={key + '-tab'}
              data-toggle='tab'
              href={'#' + key}
              role='tab'
              aria-controls={key}
              aria-selected='true'
            >
              {key}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      }
    });
  }

}

render () {
  return displayMenu();
}
```